# Send an email to users if any changes are made in the privacy policy and/or terms of service

Tags: feature-request, email, legal, policy, terms-of-service

If any changes are made in the privacy policy and/or terms of service of SE/SO, please send an email to the users (at least a month in advance before the legal agreement comes into effect).

For example (from Quora):

[image: Screenshot of mail sent by Quora]

---

Please set a good precedent :)

Comment: Terms of Service changes are emailed.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I was not an SE user in the past (when the ToS was changed). Can you please share a screenshot of the email which you received?

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Now that the Terms of Service & Privacy Policy have been changed a bit..  did you receive a mail? I didn't.

Comment: I'd say the best way to get staff attention to this would be to post an answer to the most recent announcement asking why it wasn't emailed. Most likely the answer is that they deemed the change minor enough to not send an email, but make it clear that you'd like an email for even one-character changes (e.g. the 3.0 to 4.0 license change).

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Done: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375291